# Azure SQL Server Backup: Need to UnRegister Containers and Redisover DBs in Azure SQL Server Backup using ARM templates

Tags: azure, backup, database-backups, azure-backup-vault

I have performed discovery operations for listing protectable items in Azure Backup: 'SQL in Azure VM'.

I am able to perform 'Disovery' using the following template

```
 "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers",
            "apiVersion": "2016-12-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/', parameters('fabricName'), '/',parameters('protectionContainers')[copyIndex()])]",
            "properties": {
                "backupManagementType": "[parameters('backupManagementType')]",
                "workloadType": "[parameters('workloadType')]",
                "containerType": "[parameters('protectionContainerTypes')[copyIndex()]]",
                "sourceResourceId": "[parameters('sourceResourceIds')[copyIndex()]]",
                "operationType": "Register"
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "protectionContainersCopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('protectionContainers'))]"
            }
        }
    ]
```

I similarly tried the following operation types:

"Reregister": Works as expected.
"Invalid: Did not perform any operation.

Could someone guide me with unregistering of containers using the ARM template?
(I already have the API to do it, but I need it with an ARM template).

Similarly is there any way to rediscover DBs within a registered container using an ARM template?

Any help is much appriceiated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Register API for Protection Containers, it looks like the supported values for `OperationType` are: `Invalid`, `Register` and `Reregister`. The Unregister API fires a HTTP `DELETE` request that is not straightforward to simulate with an ARM template. ARM Templates are primarily meant to be used for *creating* and *managing* your Azure resources as an IaC solution.

That said, if you have ARM templates as your only option, you could try deploying it in [Complete mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes#complete-mode). In complete mode, Resource Manager deletes resources that exist in the resource group but aren't specified in the template.

To deploy a template in Complete mode, you'd have to set it explicitly using the `Mode` parameter since the default mode is *incremental*. Be sure to use the [what-if operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell) before deploying a template in complete mode to avoid unintentionally deleting resources.